# Meaning of 盛り上げるんだよ気分を

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm looking for help with the two phrases in bold below. From what I understand his friend wants him to bring his girl friend to the party but she doesn't want to go because she is shy.

「バカ言ってんじゃねえぞテメェ！　美女がいてこそのパーティだろうが。拝み倒してでも連れてこい」

「簡単に言うけどさ」

「自分の恋人相手にダセェこと言ってんじゃねぇぞ。**盛り上げるんだよ気分を**、**高めるんだよ素敵な予感を**！」

However I'm not quite sure what his friend is actually telling him to do when he says 気分を盛り上げるんだよ, 素敵な予感を高めるんだよ. Whose 気分 is the speaker referring to here? Is he referring to the listener himself, the listener's girlfriend, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are referring to the 気分 and 予感 of the girlfriend and not the listener/speaker.